# Spring security SSO + Basic Authentication

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, basic-authentication

I would like to able security like this in my application:
Protected by OAuth2 SSO:
/app/**  ,/VAADIN/**  ,/vaadinServlet/**
Protected by Basic Authentication:
/intergration/**
And the rest of resources are opened.

```
@Component
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SingleSignOnSecurity extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
        matchers.antMatchers("/app/**", "/VAADIN/**", "/vaadinServlet/**");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().logout().permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app/**", "/VAADIN/**", "/vaadinServlet/**").authenticated();
    }
}

@Component
public class HardCodedSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/integration/**").authenticated()
           .and()
           .httpBasic()
           .and()
           .csrf().disable()
           .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

If I put `@Order` on `HardCodedSecurity` class to be `(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER + 1)`, then the SSO works, but not the Basic Auth.  `(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1)`, then the Basic Auth works, but not the SSO. I can't get both of them to work as described.

I would be thankful if you can help me to the right path here. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to get this working? I am interested as I am facing the same type of problem.